# I want to save date into a database but when i submit the form is saves the date as 1970-01-01

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is the model used to store the date.

```
public function add_client() {

        $sqlDaye = "YYYY-MM-DD";

        $data = array(

            'name' => $this->input->post('client_name'),
            'industry_id' => $this->input->post('industry'),
            'user_id' => $this->input->post('users'),
            'status_id' => $this->input->post('status'),
            'startdate' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $sqlDaye))),
            'enddate' => date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $sqlDaye))),
            'rates' => $this->input->post('rates')
        );
        $this->db->insert('clients', $data);
    }
```

Comment: can you tell me what is name of field type?

Answer (score 2):

```
 $sqlDaye = "YYYY-MM-DD";
```

`YYYY-MM-DD` is a valid ***format***, not a valid ***date***. And you are running `strtotime` on it which results in an invalid timestamp and the you get the default value returned

**strtotime**

> The function expects to be given a string containing an English date format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC), relative to the timestamp given in now, or the current time if now is not supplied.

You have to run that on a date, not on a format. Like try this

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('2014-10-10'));
                                    ^
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sqlDaye = "YYYY-MM-DD";
```

Is a string.

You cannot enter a string into a date.
'2014-11-10' is a date.